# Error in Constructor VDM++

Tags: compiler-errors, vdm++

I'm getting a stupid error in VDM++ ToolBox Academic.

When I try to run an operation it gives me this error:

```
Run-Time Error 280: No constructor with this parameter list is in scope
value: "Game"
```

My constructor is:

```
public Game: Date * Team * Team ==> Game
Game(d,t1,t2) == (
    matchday := d;
    host := t1;
    visitor := t2;
    return self;
);
```

And i call it here:

```
game := new Game(matchday1day1,groupA.teams(2),groupA.teams(3));
```

I have this declaration:

```
public groupA : Group;
public matchday1day1 : Date;
```

and (in Groups):

```
public teams : seq of Team;
```

The error points to the first letter of `Game`.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

If I read your description of the model correct then it should look like this:

```
class Group

instance variables
public teams : seq of Team := [new Team(),new Team(),new Team()];
end Group

class Team
end Team

class Date
end Date

class Game

instance variables
matchday: Date;
host : Team;
visitor : Team;

operations
public Game: Date * Team * Team ==> Game
Game(d,t1,t2) == (
    matchday := d;
    host := t1;
    visitor := t2;
    return self;
);
end Game

class Test
instance variables

public groupA : Group := new Group();
public matchday1day1 : Date := new Date();

operations

public test : ()==>()
test()== (
dcl game : Game;
 game := new Game(matchday1day1,groupA.teams(2),groupA.teams(3)) ;
)

end Test
```

Where I added Test and initialized the variables.

I don't see anything wrong here and in fact it also runs in [Overture](http://overturetool.org/) which is an other Open source tool suite for VDM. I think your specification is correct VDM. Give it a try in the Overture IDE.